# Pass a timestamp value in minDate of jquery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, timestamp, mindate

I am having trouble passing a timestamp string into the minDate property. The way I am doing it doesn't seem to work.

var timestamp = 1349802000000;

```
$( "booksale_start_date_view" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(timestamp) );
```

Is this the right way of doing it ? Sorry for my ignorance on the subject.

Comment: @MihaRekar http://jsfiddle.net/p6dvq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery UI, you should set it up like this:

```
$( "#booksale_start_date_view" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(1349802000000)});
```

If you provided jsfiddle, it would be much easier to see where you go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
  var timestamp=new Date(); //Unix Timestamp in seconds

  //But we need the time in milliseconds so,
  timestamp=timestamp*1000;
  $("booksale_start_date_view" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", timestamp);
```

Comment: i Have timestamp string ready from ajax. I cannot create a new one like you described here.